# C - Static Array with length defined by a variable

Tags: c, arrays, variables, initialization

I'm actually working on an assignement in C, and for the need of my implementation, I need to use a static array, let's say

```
static int array[LEN];
```

The trick is that this array length, `LEN`, is computed in the `main()`. For example

```
static int LEN;

void initLen(int len) {
LEN = len;
}

static int array[LEN];
```

Where `initLen` is called in the `main`, and `len` is computed using the arguments given by the user.

The issue with this design, is that I get the error

```
threadpool.c:84: error: variably modified ‘isdone’ at file scope
```

The error is due to the fact that we cannot initialize static arrays using variables as length. To make it work, I'm defining a `LEN_MAX` and write

```
#define LEN_MAX 2400

static int array[LEN_MAX]
```

The issue with this design is that i'm exposing myself for buffers overflows and segfaults :(

So I'm wondering if there is some elegant way to initialize a static array with the exact length `LEN`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `isdone` and what does it have to do with your array? Nowhere in your question, except the error message, is this `isdone` variable mentioned. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg well `isdone` is just the real array in my program, array that I simply called `array` in my example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
static int LEN;
static int* array = NULL;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    LEN = someComputedValue;
    array = malloc( sizeof( int ) * LEN );
    memset( array, 0, sizeof( int ) * LEN );
    // You can do the above two lines of code in one shot with calloc()
    // array = calloc(LEN, sizeof(int));
    if (array == NULL)
    {
       printf("Memory error!\n");
       return -1;
    }
    ....
    // When you're done, free() the memory to avoid memory leaks
    free(array);
    array = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `malloc`:

```
static int *array;

void initArray(int len) {
   if ((array = malloc(sizeof(int)*len)) != NULL) {
      printf("Allocated %d bytes of memory\n", sizeof(int)*len);
   } else {
      printf("Memory error! Could not allocate the %d bytes requested!\n", sizeof(int)*len);
   }
}
```

Now don't forget to init the array before you can use it.