# C the greatest value in random array, not working properly

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int array[];
int arraySize = 460;
int max;

int array_size(int n) {
    array[n];
}
int read_from_array(int n){
    for(int i = 0; i <= arraySize-1;i++ )
        printf("%d|",array[i]);
}
int array_generator(int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        array[i] = rand() % 1000;
}
int find_max(int n) {
    for(int i = 0;i <= n-1;i++)
    {
        if(array[i] > max)
            max = array[i];
    }
    printf("\n%d",max);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    srand(time(NULL));

    array_size(arraySize);
    array_generator(arraySize);
    //read_from_array(arraySize);
    find_max(arraySize);

    return 0;
}
```

im learning and have made something like this to find biggest int in random array
when this variable is set < 460 it works but when i make it bigger, it wont work.
int arraySize = 460;

i want to know why this is happening and how to make it better.

Comment: Do you think that `array_size[n]` sets the array size? It doesn't. As is, you array is empty and all accesses are undefined behaviour.

Comment: `int array[]` is the same as `int array[1];`

Comment: @CoolGuy, are you sure it's not the same thing as `int* array`? (As in, no storage allocated, just a pointer.)

Comment: @Tyler Yes. See my question: [What do I get if I declare an array without a size in global scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424495/what-do-i-get-if-i-declare-an-array-without-a-size-in-global-scope). I agree that it isn't 100% equivalent though...

Comment: why do you need to use array_size why do you not just declare int array[arraysize] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of stuff.

Firstly, your array is never actually allocated. You're putting all those random integers into... who knows where. The easy way to fix this is to put a number in the `[]` after the array declaration. But to do this, the size has to be a constant, so you can't use a variable like `arraySize` to set the size. You can use a preprocessor `#define`, though. Like so:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 460
int array[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Your `array_size` function doesn't do anything.

All of your functions are declared to return an `int`, but there's no `return` statement. Either make them `void` or return something.

Your `max` should be a local variable inside `find_max` and it should be given a value before you try to use it in the `if` statement.

```
int find_max(int n) {
    int max = array[0];
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        if(array[i] > max)
            max = array[i];
    }
    printf("\n%d",max);
    return max;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void array_init(int* array, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % 1000;
    }
}

int array_max(int* array, int n) {
    int max = array[0];
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        if(array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int array_size = 460;
    int array[array_size];

    array_init(array, array_size);
    int max = array_max(array, array_size);
    printf("%d\n", max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_you can't use a variable like arraySize to set the size_" -- Read up on [Variable Length Arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Comment: I'm aware. Better to keep it simple. And it doesn't apply to static (edit: "statically allocated" e.g. global) arrays anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882650/c-static-array-with-length-defined-by-a-variable

Comment: so #define ARRAY_SIZE anyvalue is a good practice or it should be just static from begining int array[1000];

Comment: Opinions on define vary. Personally, I would rework it to where the array is declared and allocated in `main()` and passed around to the other functions for them to modify/process. Give me a sec and I'll edit to show you.

Comment: what happens when i try to make array_size = 520896 or more ? it terminates, is it something with ram or compiler

Comment: Idk, works fine for me. Try here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php.

Answer (score 0):

`max` is never initialised, and may start wth a value that is larger then your array's largest value.  It should be initialised thus:

```
#include <limits.h>

int max = INT_MIN ;  // Init. to smallest possible value.
```